# How to check if particular Key and Value is available in JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I've a JSONArray and I need to fetch if particular key value is available in this JSONArray. Lets say, I have a specific key value pair like *Current Employment Status:False* and I need to verify if this key value pair is available in my JSONArray or not. My JSONArray is below:

```
[
   {
      "last_seen":1557908766238,
      "distinct_id":"11cb639f-cbf7-499c- a1cf-e3ff4466a093",
      "time":1557908766238,
      "properties":{
         "$browser_version":74,
         "$name":"Jessica Claire",
         "$timezone":"Asia/Kolkata",
         "$os":"Windows",
         "$email":"19_05_15_135529631_ebMPR@email-qa.livecareer.com",
         "$initial_referring_domain":"$direct",
         "userid":"11cb639f-cbf7-499c-a1cf-e3ff4466a093",
         "$first_name":"Jessica",
         "Current Employment Status":"FALSE",
         "enter builder":1,
         "fedex experience":"FALSE",
         "ResumeTips Permission":"TRUE",
         "id":"11cb639f-cbf7-499c-a1cf-e3ff4466a093",
         "LCNews Permission":"TRUE",
         "Document Creation Mode":"scratch",
         "Email Valid":"False",
         "$last_name":"Claire",
         "Payment Status":"Not Started",
         "Work Experience Modal":"TRUE",
         "$city":"Noida",
         "Subscription Status":"FALSE",
         "Job Alerts Permission":"TRUE",
         "sign up":1,
         "$browser":"Chrome",
         "userId":"11cb639f-cbf7-499c-a1cf-e3ff4466a093",
         "$country_code":"IN",
         "$region":"Uttar Pradesh",
         "One Time Purchase":"FALSE",
         "$last_seen":"2019-05-15T08:26:06.000Z",
         "Last enter builder":"2019-05-15T08:24:01.000Z",
         "Last sign up":"2019-05-15T08:26:03.000Z",
         "$initial_referrer":"$direct",
         "EduOps Permission":"TRUE"
      },
      "labels":[

      ]
   }
]
```

It should print true if present and false if not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JsonArray and JsonObject to do that. Use org.json maven dependency.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {

        String sb = "[{\"last_seen\":1557908766238,\"distinct_id\":\"11cb639f-cbf7-499c- a1cf-e3ff4466a093\",\"time\":1557908766238,\"properties\": {\"$browser_version\":74,\"$name\":\"Jessica Claire\",\"$timezone\":\"Asia/Kolkata\",\"$os\":\"Windows\",\"$email\":\"19_05_15_135529631_ebMPR@email-qa.livecareer.com\",\"$initial_referring_domain\":\"$direct\",\"userid\":\"11cb639f-cbf7-499c-a1cf-e3ff4466a093\",\"$first_name\":\"Jessica\",\"Current Employment Status\":\"FALSE\",\"enter builder\":1,\"fedex experience\":\"FALSE\",\"ResumeTips Permission\":\"TRUE\",\"id\":\"11cb639f-cbf7-499c-a1cf-e3ff4466a093\",\"LCNews Permission\":\"TRUE\",\"Document Creation Mode\":\"scratch\",\"Email Valid\":\"False\",\"$last_name\":\"Claire\",\"Payment Status\":\"Not Started\",\"Work Experience Modal\":\"TRUE\",\"$city\":\"Noida\",\"Subscription Status\":\"FALSE\",\"Job Alerts Permission\":\"TRUE\",\"sign up\":1,\"$browser\":\"Chrome\",\"userId\":\"11cb639f-cbf7-499c-a1cf-e3ff4466a093\",\"$country_code\":\"IN\",\"$region\":\"Uttar Pradesh\",\"One Time Purchase\":\"FALSE\",\"$last_seen\":\"2019-05-15T08:26:06.000Z\",\"Last enter builder\":\"2019-05-15T08:24:01.000Z\",\"Last sign up\":\"2019-05-15T08:26:03.000Z\",\"$initial_referrer\":\"$direct\",\"EduOps Permission\":\"TRUE\"},\"labels\":[]}]";
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Object value = null;
            try {
                JSONObject properties = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("properties");
            value = properties.get("Current Employment Status");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                //print flase if not found
                System.out.println("false");
            }
            //print the value if found
            System.out.println("Value =" + value);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working, if you observe there is further jsonObject inside this jsonarray with the name of Properties and "Current Employment Status" value is inside that json. I need to verify "Current Employment Status" along with the value("false" in this json). Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I had stored this json in a file named findKey.json

```java
        String path = "others\\findKey.json";
        File f = new File(path);
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(f));

        JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            if (arr.get(i) instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject jsonobject = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                JSONObject props = (JSONObject) jsonobject.get("properties");
                String key = (String) props.get("Current Employment Status");
                //print true if key is found and equals to false
                Boolean output= (key != null && key.equals("FALSE"))? true:false;
                System.out.println(output);

            }
        }
```

don't forget to use json-simple

Answer (score 0):

I Have used a jar to parse String into JSon

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String temp = "[{\"last_seen\":1557908766238,\"distinct_id\":\"11cb639f-cbf7-499c- "
            + "a1cf-e3ff4466a093\",\"time\":1557908766238,\"properties\": {\"$browser_version\":74,"
            + " \" $name\":\"Jessica Claire\",\"$timezone\":\"AsiaKolkata\","
            + "\"$os\":\"Windows\",\"$email\":\"19_05_15_135529631_ebMPR@email-qa.livecareer.com\",\"$initial_referring_domain\":\"$direct\",\"userid\":\"11cb639f-cbf7-499c-a1cf-e3ff4466a093\",\"$first_name\":\"Jessica\",\"Current Employment Status\":\"FALSE\",\"enter builder\":1,\"fedex experience\":\"FALSE\",\"ResumeTips Permission\":\"TRUE\",\"id\":\"11cb639f-cbf7-499c-a1cf-e3ff4466a093\",\"LCNews Permission\":\"TRUE\",\"Document Creation Mode\":\"scratch\",\"Email Valid\":\"False\",\"$last_name\":\"Claire\",\"Payment Status\":\"Not Started\",\"Work Experience Modal\":\"TRUE\",\"$city\":\"Noida\",\"Subscription Status\":\"FALSE\",\"Job Alerts Permission\":\"TRUE\",\"sign up\":1,\"$browser\":\"Chrome\",\"userId\":\"11cb639f-cbf7-499c-a1cf-e3ff4466a093\",\"$country_code\":\"IN\",\"$region\":\"Uttar Pradesh\",\"One Time Purchase\":\"FALSE\",\"$last_seen\":\"2019-05-15T08:26:06.000Z\",\"Last enter builder\":\"2019-05-15T08:24:01.000Z\",\"Last sign up\":\"2019-05-15T08:26:03.000Z\",\"$initial_referrer\":\"$direct\",\"EduOps Permission\":\"TRUE\"},\"labels\":[]}]";

String findkeyvalue = "Current Employment Status:False";


boolean flag =  FindValue(temp , findkeyvalue);

System.out.println(flag);
}

private static boolean FindValue(String temp, String findkeyvalue) {
    try {
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(temp);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(array.get(i).toString());
             return  travertillLast(array.get(i).toString() , findkeyvalue);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean   travertillLast(String string, String findkeyvalue) throws ParseException {
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(string);

    System.out.println(jsonObj);
       for (Object key : jsonObj.keySet()) {
            //based on you key types
            String keyStr = (String)key;
            Object keyvalue = jsonObj.get(keyStr);

            //Print key and value
            String keyandValuue = keyStr + ":" + keyvalue;
            System.out.println(keyandValuue);
            if(keyandValuue.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(findkeyvalue)){
                return true;
            }

            //for nested objects iteration if required
            if (keyvalue instanceof JSONObject)
                return travertillLast(keyvalue+"",findkeyvalue);
        }
    return false;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```